# Using UIButton to refresh the UItableViewCell content

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

There are two components, UItableView and a UIButton, in my app.

The UItableViewcell will load the data from remote database fulfilled by JSON.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"tableidentifier"
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier]; 

if (cell == nil) { 
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier] autorelease]; 
} 
NSDictionary *voc_list=[listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",voc_list);
cell.textLabel.text = [[(NSDictionary*)voc_list objectForKey:@"vocabulary_list"]objectForKey:@"Vocabulary"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[(NSDictionary*)voc_list objectForKey:@"vocabulary_list"]objectForKey:@"Translation"];

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];


return cell; }
```

However, I want to refresh all the table content when user press the button, and I try to implement the following code:

```
 -(IBAction)historyPressed:(id)sender{
     isToogle = !isToogle;
     if(isToogle){
          // Back to original table content

     }else{

       // Following codes will communicate with remote server and filter data to the app.
       // The app go smooth here.       

        NSError *error = NULL;
        NSDictionary *getStuID=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:student_id,@"Stu_ID", nil];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:getStuID options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
        [self sendTOcompareByJSON:jsonData];



        //Following codes are trying to show/refresh the data on tableview, but the app will go crash.
        CGPoint location            = [sender locationInView:self.table];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath      = [self.table indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
        UITableViewCell *new_cell=[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];



        historyList_= [NSArray arrayWithArray:personalized_history];
        NSDictionary *dic = [historyList_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        new_cell.textLabel.text=[[(NSDictionary*)dic objectForKey:@"history_list"]objectForKey:@"Vocabulary"];
        new_cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[(NSDictionary*)dic objectForKey:@"history_lsit"]objectForKey:@"Score"];


    }


    }
```

Comment: you have a simple option to update data used in data sources of table and reload the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

In the historypressed method just try to call [yourtableview reloaddata].. After your setting of all the cell content do reloaddata,it will refresh the tableview.

Comment: I just add the method [self.table relaodData], but it still go crash.

Comment: you are setting the data for a particular row using cellforrowatindexpath? How many rows you have and for how many rows you are setting the data? If you have suppose 10 rows and you set the data for 1 row.. it will crash. Try to set data for all rows atlease try to do the json data storing and setting of data in cellforrowatindexpath method. There you cannot miss any cell.

Comment: I got the reason why the app go crash by your comment. But I have no idea to set data for all rows. In the ˋ-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:ˋ method, it will help me set all data to each cell. Should I use the for loop in the button action to fulfill the effect? 
I am a beginner, hope you dont mind these trivial problem.

Comment: no.. if you do not want to set data to a particular row don't set it set it like cell.textlabel.text = @""; otherwise if you want to set data then set using your array

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you getting data from `[self sendTOcompareByJSON:jsonData];`. If its a sync call, to webserver, then you can just update your datasource (in ur case you are filling tableview using `listData`) just after this.So once the `listData` is updated with the new contents, then you should reload your tableview like this `[self.table reloadData]`

If its an async call to web server, then do update the datasource and reload the table on callback.

Hope this helps.